# Difficulty on finding the correct User Agent of a device

Tags: php

I want to know when a Windows Phone is on page so having it's user agent that is

```
   Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows Phone OS 7.5; Trident/5.0; IEMobile/9.0;)
```

I use this code, without luck. What am I missing here?

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], Windows Phone) == false) {
 echo"mango";
 }
```

I also tried Phone, IEMobile but nothing.

Comment: FYI, use `=== false` with `strpos()`

Comment: @Phil thanks for the tip, but I have the same result

Comment: And some "" around "Windows Phone"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're missing some quotes around your search string. Also, you appear to be checking for the wrong condition. `strpos()` returns `false` if it *can't* find the string. You want to check for non-false results

```
// using stripos for case-insensitive search
if (stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'windows phone') !== false) {
    echo 'mango';
}
```